Error: "spawn ENOENT" when trying to launch WinKeyServer.exe in Node.js application
I have created a time tracker application using react and electron.js.
After first installation of the desktop application, when I start timer for the first time an error pops-up and when I click okay it'll carry on. It'll cause no issues whatsoever but it's bugging me. Can't tell why it's popping up. [Only for the first time]. I can't even figure out where is this error coming to so I could provide some code snippet.
Please feel free to ask anything or provide any guide how I should troubleshoot it.
Error pop-up

The file u r trying to access does not exist on the path. Please cross check

I'm not requesting winkeyserver.exe. Maybe this is coming from node-global-keylistener.
